# How to create multiple lines plot with custom offset in Y-axis in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I add a custom y-offset in ggplot?  The [hyperspec package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hyperSpec/index.html) kind of does the job but it does not match well with ggplot.

`facet` or `grid.arrange` can put multiple line plots on the same page but the plots are not overlapping.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Hyperspec](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hyperSpec/index.html) does in fact support ggplot2 via the [plotspc()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hyperSpec/versions/0.99-20180627/topics/plotspc) function.

Another option is simply to manipulate your data and add an offset to y based on category before plotting.

Finally, if you don't mind adding another dependency, you can use [ggstance::position_dodgev](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggstance/ggstance.pdf), which is the vertical equivalent of the built-in [ggplot2::position_dodge](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with manipulating the data:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
economics_long %>%  # from ggplot2
  mutate(offset = variable %>% as.factor %>% as.numeric) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value01 + offset, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]